# Does a modular power supply come with all the cables?

Tags: power-supply

I'm looking to buy a modular psu, because a non modular one is a complete pain. I'm wondering if all the cables will come with the psu. This is the one I'm looking to buy.

[http://www.amazon.com/Corsair-Series-80PLUS-Gold-Certified-Supply/dp/B00EB7UIXM/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1407470927&sr=8-1&keywords=corsair+850+watt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EB7UIXM)

Comment: According to at least one product review on that page, it comes with the cables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Every modular power supply I've ever purchased has included a variety of cables, all that you could possibly need in a reasonable PC build (even in some unreasonable ones, like my scrypt coin mining rigs, which needed way more power connections than any normal PC should). This particular one explicitly says "Low-profile, flat cable design reduces air friction and helps maximize airflow through your computer's chassis." which indicates, to me, that this power supply includes low-profile cables.

Comment: You didn't scroll the page, since you would also have seen:  
**Flat black, low-profile modular cables**  
You can use only the cables you need, and leave the rest in the box for fast, easy, and great-looking builds.